# Identifying correct window frame size for filling background color

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing in Cocoa, and I am currently having problems with filling the background of a `NSWindowController`.

I understand that subclassing is the way forward if you want to customise your cocoa app. So I created a custom `NSView` named whiteView and added this view as a subview to my `windowController`'s `contentView`; however, there are some issues with completely filling the background of the window. Can anyone explain how I can have the color cover the complete surface area of the window's frame pls. Thank you

These are the results that I have so far.

**1) This is the window when I leave it as it is, notice the white color only having covered half of the window.**
[image: When I dont have the window maximised]

**2)Here is the same window again when I adjust the window far to the right and bottom. The white screen seems to stretch enough so that it covers the elements.**
[image]

This is how I create the custom view

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}
```

And this how I achieve plaster the view onto my window.

```
WhiteView *whiteBackgroundView = [[WhiteView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:whiteBackgroundView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:self.window.contentView];
```

What do I need to do to correctly allow for my window's background to be fully covered in white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the simple solution is to use `-[NSWindow setBackgroundColor:]` to just set the window's background color. No need for a view.

If you're still interested in how to fix the view-based approach, probably what's wrong is that you haven't set the autoresizing mask of the view to make it follow the changes in the window size. For example, you could do `[whiteBackgroundView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable]`.

However, you could also set the `whiteBackgroundView` as the window's `contentView` rather than as a subview of it. The window's content view is always kept at the size necessary to fill the window's content rect. All of the other views of your window would be subviews of the white background view. In my opinion, this is better than making it a sibling that just happens to be at the back. Using relative ordering among siblings views to achieve a particular rendering order is a hack.

Finally, there's no reason to invoke `super`'s implementation in your `-drawRect:` if the superclass is `NSView` itself. `NSView` doesn't do any drawing in its `-drawRect:`. Also, your subclass takes over full responsibility for the entire drawn contents of its bounds, so you'd overdraw whatever `super` had drawn, anyway. (Also, you need only fill `dirtyRect` rather than `[self bounds]`.)

While you're at it, since your class fills its bounds, you should override `-isOpaque` to return `YES` for optimization.

---

Update: regarding the frame of the view: if it's not going to be the window's content view, then you want to set its frame to be its prospective superview's bounds. So, you should have used `self.window.contentView.bounds` if you wanted `whiteBackgroundView` to fill the content view.

More generally, if you want the content rect of a window, you would do `[window contentRectForFrameRect:window.frame]`. But if a view is going to be a window's content view, there's no need to set its frame to anything in particular. It will be resized automatically.

---

Update 2:

To transfer the view hierarchy from the original content view to the new content view (when you're making the white background view the content view):

```
NSArray* subviews = [self.window.contentView.subviews copy];
[subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[whiteBackgroundView setSubviews:subviews];
[subviews release];
```

(Written for manual retain-release. If using ARC, just drop the `-release` invocation.)

Regarding the frame to use, as mentioned in the first update: keep in mind that the view's frame should be expressed in the coordinate system of its superview. So, as I said, `self.window.contentView.bounds` would work if you're putting the new view into the content view. The window's frame and content rect are in **screen** coordinates. They would be completely incorrect for positioning a view.

Comment: Hey thank you for posting. So like you mentioned, it might be better to set the contentView as opposed to adding my custom view as a sibling of the contentView, but doing so draws a white layer on what either seems to be on top of the UI elements, or it completely overwrites it. Is there a specific way I should be going about setting it as the contentView so as to save the UI elements from being drawn over/removed?

Comment: Also, wen I set the `autoresizingMask` property to the two values, in which ever order theyre written, only the Width sizable value seems to be affecting the whiteBackground view and not the heightSizable. The height behaves the same as shown in the two reference images above, but the width works like a charm now. Is there anything else for me to try or anything I need to do to get the resizingMasks to work the way we expect it to work.

Comment: Did you miss the first paragraph about just setting the window's background color? Also, if you set your custom view as the window's content view, then you've effectively removed all of the views that were set up in IB. Those are subviews of the original content view but that was removed and is no longer in the window (and will be released if nothing else retains it). You need to transfer the subviews from the old content view to your new one before replacing it. I'll update my answer to show that. Regarding the `autoresizingMask`, did you fix the custom view's frame?

Comment: Hey, yes I did. I forgot to mention, that yes, that definitely does work, although I'd prefer if I were to solve this situation with the ustom view in place so that I'm able to continue customising it. I did fix the what you told me to do regarding the selfbounds and replacing it with dirtyrect instead. Is that what youre referring to when youre asking whether I 'fixed the custom view's frame'?

Comment: No, that's not what I was talking about. See the first update. You're passing the wrong frame to the custom view's `-initWithFrame:` method.

Comment: Great, so I was passing in the wrong frame. I assume window.frame did not work because those coordinates were relative to my computer screen and are actually interested in only the contentView's frame since that is relative to the application window itself?

Comment: Just one last thing, so you stated that I shouldnt set the subviews the way I showed because its hackish and that I should instead copy the current subviews and then add those subviews to my customerView and then set that customView to the window's contentView, right? Isn't that hackish itself? Just curious buddy. Would ideally like to stick to one method which I'll then apply to future custom classes.

Comment: The least hackish way would be to set the window background color. The next least hackish way would be to set the class of the content view to your custom class in IB in the Identity inspector. After that, I would say swapping the content view at runtime and transferring the subview hierarchy. In my opinion, relying on one view to draw a background behind its siblings is the most hackish. Regarding the frame: you want the content view's **bounds** (not its frame) because that's the view that you want your custom view to fill. A view's frame is always in terms of its superview's bounds.